# Não consigo cadastrar um registro no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    session_start();
        if(!(isset($_SESSION['usuario']))){
            header("location: index.php");
        }

    include './classes/Conexao.class.php';
    include './classes/DAO/EmpresasDAO.class.php';
    include './classes/entidades/Empresas.class.php';

    $EmpresasDAO = new EmpresasDAO();
    $Empresas = new Empresas();

    //ação para inserir um novo cadastro na base de dados
    require_once './actions/inserirEmpresas.action.php';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>SIGIO - PAINEL</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.painel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

    <div class="panelbar">
        <div class="userTools">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>
                    <?php echo strtoupper($_SESSION['usuario']);?>
                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <button type="button" class="dropdown-item btn-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        Perfil
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="dropdown-item btn-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
                        Configurações
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="dropdown-item btn-sm">
                        <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
                        Ajuda
                    </button>

                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

                    <button type="button" class="dropdown-item btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-logout">
                        <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
                        Sair
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="modal-logout" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-logout" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Deseja Realmente Sair?</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Sim, Desejo.</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--userTools-->
    </div><!--panelbar-->

    <div class="systemTools">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-inserir">Novo Registro</button>
    </div><!--systemTools-->

    <div class="tabela-dados table-responsive-md">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">CNPJ</th>
                    <th scope="col">Razão Social</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nome Fantasia</th>
                    <th scope="col">Telefone</th>
                    <th scope="col">Celular</th>
                    <th scope="col">Contato Responsável</th>
                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                    <th scope="col">Ações</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <!--exibição do corpo da tabela listar do painel-->
                <?php require_once './actions/listarEmpresas.action.php';?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div><!--tabela-dados-->

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-inserir" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-inserir" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h6 class="modal-title">Inserir Novo Registro</h6>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <form action="painel.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cnpj" maxlength="14" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <label for="razao">Razão Social</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="razao" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label for="fantasia">Nome Fantasia</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fantasia" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label for="logradouro">Logradouro</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="logradouro">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label for="bairro">Bairro</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bairro">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label for="cidade">Cidade</label>
                                <select class="custom-select" name="cidade" required>
                                    <option selected>Selecione a Cidade</option>
                                    <option value="Jaboatão dos Guararapes">Jaboatão dos Guararapes</option>
                                    <option value="Recife">Recife</option>
                                    <option value="Olinda">Olinda</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefone" maxlength="10" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label for="celular">Celular</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="celular" maxlength="11" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" maxlength="30" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label for="responsavel">Contato Responsável</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="responsavel" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label for="status">Status</label>
                                <select class="custom-select" name="status" required>
                                    <option selected>Selecione o Status</option>
                                    <option value="Contato Futuro">A Contatar</option>
                                    <option value="Contato Feito">Contato Feito</option>
                                    <option value="Contato Interrompido">Contato Interrompido</option>
                                    <option value="A Visitar">A Visitar</option>
                                    <option value="Visitado">Visitado</option>
                                    <option value="A Fechar">A Fechar</option>
                                    <option value="Fechado">Fechado</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <label for="usuario">Usuário</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <label for="observacao">Observações</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="observacao" rows="2"></textarea><br/>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div><!--modal-body-->

                    <input type="text" hidden="" name="usuario" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?>">

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" value="Limpar Campos">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--exibição dos modais de visualização de cadastros-->
    <?php require_once './actions/verEmpresas.action.php';?>

    <!--exibição dos modais de edição de cadastros-->

    </body>
</html>







<?php

    class Conexao{
        private $db_user   = "root";
        private $db_pass   = "root";
        private $db_route  = "localhost";
        private $db_schema = "sigio_prospects";
        private $con       = "";

        public function __construct(){
            $this->con = mysqli_connect($this->db_route, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass) or die ("A Conexão com o Banco de Dados Falhou! " .mysqli_error($this->con));
            mysqli_select_db($this->con, $this->db_schema) or die ("A Conexão com o Banco de Dados Falhou! " . mysqli_error($this->con));
        }

        public function getCon(){
            return $this->con;
        }
    }






<?php

    class EmpresasDAO {
        private $conexao;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->conexao = new Conexao();
        }

        public function inserir($Empresas){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO empresas (cnpj, razao_empresas, fantasia_empresas, logradouro_empresas, bairro_empresas, cidade_empresas, responsavel_empresas, telefone_empresas"
                    . "email_empresas, status_empresas, observacao_empresas, usuario_cadastro) VALUES ("
                    . "'" . $Empresas->getCnpj() ."', '" . $Empresas->getRazao() ."',
                    . '" . $Empresas->getFantasia() ."','" . $Empresas->getLogradouro() ."', 
                    '" . $Empresas->getBairro() ."', '" . $Empresas->getCidade() ."',"
                    . "'" . $Empresas->getResponsavel() ."','" . $Empresas->getTelefone() ."',
                    '" . $Empresas->getCelular() ."','" . $Empresas->getEmail() ."',"
                    . "'" . $Empresas->getStatus() ."','" . $Empresas->getObservacao() ."',"
                    . "'" . $Empresas->getUsuario() ."' )";
            if(mysqli_query($this->conexao->getCon(), $sql)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

```
        $Empresas->setCnpj($cnpj);
        $Empresas->setRazao($razao);
        $Empresas->setFantasia($fantasia);
        $Empresas->setLogradouro($logradouro);
        $Empresas->setBairro($bairro);
        $Empresas->setCidade($cidade);
        $Empresas->setResponsavel($responsavel);
        $Empresas->setTelefone($telefone);
        $Empresas->setCelular($celular);
        $Empresas->setEmail($email);
        $Empresas->setStatus($status);
        $Empresas->setObservacao($observacao);
        $Empresas->setUsuario($usuario);

        $resultado = $EmpresasDAO->inserir($Empresas);
            if($resultado == true){
                header('location: painel.php');
            }else{
                echo 'Falha ao inserir empresa!';
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Poderia informar qual é a mensagem de erro, código ou coisa do tipo...

Comment: Pior que não retorna nenhum erro, só a mensagem do else que eu coloquei no action. Editei no post e coloquei a parte em que eu falo que retorna a mensagem de: "Falha ao inserir empresa!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu erro está na variável SQL dentro da classe empresasDAO, no método inserir, onde você gera os campos para inserção, e ao pular linha e concatenar os dados da query, esqueceu de colocar uma vírgula entre os campos:

```
[...] telefone_empresas," // A vírgula foi esquecida neste ponto...
. "email_empresas, [...]
```

Sugiro que, para que consiga ver quando ocorrer erros, coloque a sua query sendo executada para dentro de uma variável e depois a leia ou a retorne...

Lendo direto na classe (Não é legal para classe DAO, use para ver os resultados ao testar apenas):

```
$res = mysqli_query($link->getCon(), $query) or die(mysqli_error($link->getCon()));

if ($res) {
   print "Ok, Cadastrado!";
} else {
   print "$res";
}
```

Ou retornando:

```
return $res = mysqli_query($link->getCon(), $query) or die(mysqli_error($link->getCon()));
```

Comment: Muito Obrigada!